# PowerBI - Datetime to Date Conversion - 2024 Leap Day - Displays the Previous Day

Tags: date, datetime, powerbi, transform

I have the following date column:

[image]

If I apply a "Change Type" function to it to convert it from a datetime to a date:

> = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date.Date", type date}})

The resulting date is:

[image]

Is that right? Is there some sort of leap second in here? Why do I see the datetime difference when I convert types?